# MySQL GROUP BY query group results by day

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table named "counter" that has 3 fields:

```
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| record | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| passed | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The data I store is like this

```
mysql> SELECT record, passed FROM counter;
+---------------------+--------+
| record              | passed |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2019-09-19 00:00:00 |      1 |
```

What I want to do is a query to get the results of a specific day.

I used that query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d-%m-%Y %H') AS ts, 
       COUNT(*) AS passed 
FROM counter 
GROUP BY ts 
HAVING ts = 09;
```

The problem is that it will return the day 09 of every month if there is several months on the database.

```
+---------------+--------+
| ts            | passed |
+---------------+--------+
| 09-10-2019 10 |    593 |
| 09-10-2019 11 |    667 |
| 09-10-2019 12 |    367 |
| 09-10-2019 13 |     35 |
+---------------+--------+
```

I want to get an exact date, I tried to put exact date

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d-%m-%Y %H') AS ts, 
       COUNT(*) AS passed 
FROM counter 
WHERE 09-10-2019;
```

But I get an error

> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'iot.counter.record'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: The title is inconsistent from the code you posted. You want to group by day or group by day + hour of day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're including the hour inside the date format which means each day will have up to 24 sub-groups... one for each hour of day. Remove the `%H` and fix the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d-%m-%Y') AS ts, COUNT(*)
FROM counter
WHERE record >= '2019-10-09'
AND   record <  '2019-10-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just get the data for 9th hour on current date, you don't really need to consider data for whole day and then do a aggregation and filter out using having clause. This is unnecessarily inefficient, due to increased data tree lookups as well as increased temp table size (which gets discarded eventually).

Instead, you can just use `WHERE` clause to filter out the data and count:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM counter
WHERE record >= '2019-10-09 09:00:00' 
  AND record <  '2019-10-09 10:00:00'
```

Above query will benefit significantly from a Covering Index on `(record)` column.